# smallest consecutive integers such that $n$ $|$ ($p_x$#)$/3$ and $n+1$ $|$ $q^x$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, exponentiation

What are the list of smallest integers $n$ such that $$\frac{(p_{x_{\#}})}{3} \mid n \text{ and }3^{x-1} \mid n+1?$$ Here $p_x$ denotes the $x$th prime and $p_x$# is the product of all primes less than or equal to $p_x$. of course there exists a power of $3$ such that all the primes less than or equal to $p_x$ except for $3$ divide $3^{x-1}$ but this may not be the smallest integer $n$ such that this is true for. Can someone please show me a further list than mine:

$2 \mid 2$; $3 \mid 3$

$(2\cdot 5) \mid 80$; $3^4 = 81 \mid 81$

$(2 \cdot 5 \cdot7) \mid 350$; $3^3 \mid 351$

$(2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11) \mid 60830$; $3^4 \mid 60831$

$(2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13) \mid 310310$; $3^5 \mid 310311$

$(2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17) \mid 92742650$; $3^6 \mid 92742651$

$(2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7\cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19) \mid 5923277360$; $3^7 \mid 5923277361$

and so on.........

Thanks in advance. FYI $q = 3$ is an example. In general, find the smallest integer $n$ such that $$\frac{(p_{x_{\#}})}{p_i} \mid n \text{ and }3^{x-1} \mid n+1$$ for any prime $q$. (Here $p_x$ is the $x$th prime).

Comment: 80 divides 10? 81 divides 9? How? I think you have the order or this wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: You got that right, at least you see the pattern in the integers?

Comment: I see what you're attempting to show yes, but could you edit the question to prevent confusion on your behalf and others?

Comment: I am hoping for someone to show me an output of a program or something else that has a list of terms up to say, $x$ $=$ $30$ or more.

Comment: For any given $x$ this is just an application of Chinese remainder theorem.  I have no idea what you mean by $q=3$??

Comment: I could have done something like $q=5$, then we would have $n$ $|$ $(2*3*7*11*13*17*19)$; $n+1$ $|$ $5^7$. Same idea, just excluding one prime factor

Comment: @J.Linne Please add your clarifying remarks to the *question*, not the comments section.

Comment: @J.Linne Please also rewrite your question so that it makes sense.  "$3^3 \mid 81$" is true; "$81 \mid 3^3$" is false.  You can use \mid instead of | for better formatting.

Comment: Actually, looking the question a bit closely, it seems you have an error in the first calculation. 2 is the $p_1$ and thus $ x=1$ , $2 \mid 2$ and $ 3 \neq 3^{1-1}=1 \mid 3$